# How to build c++20 using modules with autotools?

Tags: c++, c++20, autotools, automake, c++-modules

This is the project:

Source program using the keyword *import*: hello.cpp

```
import <iostream>;
#include "config.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World, " << "Version: " << VERSION << std::endl;
}
```

The file configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.71])
AC_INIT([hello], [0.1.7], [jv120257@gmail.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([hello.cc])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wno-portability])

AC_PROG_CXX

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The Makefile.am:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++23 -fmodules-ts

bin_PROGRAMS=hello
hello_SOURCES=hello.cc

%.c++m:
    $(CXX) -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header $(notdir $(basename $@))
```

Observe the last sentence "%.c++m"; this is not standard what force me to use AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wno-portability]). If the "%" is removed to become compliant with standard, I get the messages below:

```
 cd . && /bin/sh /home/ventura/c/hello/missing automake-1.16 --gnu Makefile
 cd . && /bin/sh ./config.status Makefile depfiles
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ventura/c/hello'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/iostream.c++m', needed by 'hello.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ventura/c/hello'
make: *** [Makefile:277: all] Error 2
```

How can I integrate -std=c++20 modules in the GNU autotools build system ???

For now I am using the old "%" but, other problem rise from this, iostream module is always compiled ignoring the gmc.cache/.../iostream.gmc time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I integrate -std=c++20 modules in the GNU autotools build system ?

The root cause is in your compiler and / or C++ standard library, not in the Autotools. g++ is generating a dependency rule naming `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/iostream.c++m` as a prerequisite of `hello.o`, but that is erroneous because no such file is actually provided by the system or generated by the build process.  Even if that were a correct dependency, an unprivileged compilation should not be able to generate that file.

That's a bug in g++, and you should report it if it has not been reported already.

However, you should also understand this in the context that modules are (still in 2023) a pretty new language feature, and [G++ support for them is not only buggy, but also incomplete](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html).  In particular, it is documented that ...

> The Standard Library is not provided as importable header units. If
> you want to import such units, you must explicitly build them first.
> If you do not do this with care, you may have multiple declarations,
> which the module machinery must merge—compiler resource usage can be
> affected by how you partition header files into header units.

**That's a mess that I recommend just avoiding.  That is, by not `import`ing standard library header units.**  Create and use your own modules if you like, but your tools are not well suited for using system library header units.  Consider also that if you are building software that you intend to distribute to others, then any use of modules at all introduces a dependency on pretty recent build tools that can be troublesome for them.

---

If you nevertheless want to build the modules then I anticipate that your best option will be to do this:

1. Create a rule or rules to build the modules to files in the build tree.  Use an ordinary rule, not a pattern rule, because you're going to need to explicitly designate all the needed modules anyway.  I think something like this should do it:

   ```
   AM_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts
   SYSTEM_MODULES = iostream.c++m

   $(SYSTEM_MODULES):
           $(CXX) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -xc++-system-header $($@:.c++m=) -o $@
   ```
2. Persuade `make` to actually generate those modules at need.  This is a bit messy, since you would prefer to avoid manually creating or maintaining dependency lists for individual object files.  There are no great options, but the best available is probably to make all the C++ objects depend on all the selected system modules, via a prerequisite-only rule along these lines:

   ```
   $(hello_SOURCES:.cc=.o): $(SYSTEM_MODULES)
   ```

   That should work reliably to build the module files.  There are circumstances under which it could lead to modules being rebuilt when they didn't need to be, but that should not be the norm.

I cannot promise that that will work around the bug in g++'s dependency generator, or if it does, that it will continue to do so in future g++ releases that do not actually fix the bug.  If g++ continues to generate bogus dependency information for system header units, then you should be able to suppress most unneeded recompilation of those units by adding a rule with a do-nothing recipe, such as this:

```
%.c++m:
        :
```

That will, of course, re-introduce the compatibility warnings, but the compatibility impact is small because you would not be relying on this rule to build any files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Update your configure.ac file to include the AC_LANG_CXX macro, which will enable C++ language support in the Autoconf configure script:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.71])
AC_INIT([hello], [0.1.7], [jv120257@gmail.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([hello.cc])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wno-portability])

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG_CXX

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Update your Makefile.am file to use the AM_CXXFLAGS variable to include the -std=c++20 option for C++20 language support:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++20 -fmodules-ts

bin_PROGRAMS=hello
hello_SOURCES=hello.cc

%.c++m:
    $(CXX) -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header $(notdir $(basename $@))
```

Note that you should use -std=c++20 instead of -std=c++23 since C++23 is not yet finalized and not all compilers support it.

Update your source file hello.cpp to use the import statement for including the iostream module:

```
import <iostream>;
#include "config.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World, " << "Version: " << VERSION << std::endl;
}
```

Try that and see if C++20 module support using the GNU autotools build system works. Note that the iostream module should be automatically cached by the compiler, so you should not need to recompile it every time you build your project.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I integrate -std=c++20 modules in the GNU autotools build
> system

You can not.

Autotools is not equipped with the functionality required to handle the dependency scanning mechanism for modules (which [differs fundamentally](https://mathstuf.fedorapeople.org/fortran-modules/fortran-modules.html) from the compilation model in a pre-modules world).

It is possible to make this particular example compile, since you are only importing a standard library header. Ideally, you would import the standard library [through the C++23 named module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154680/how-to-use-module-std-with-gcc) (`import std`) instead of importing it via header units.

But this is only possible because the standard library headers *never change*. As soon as you require correct incremental rebuilds when one of your module source files change (which is the whole point of having a build system in the first place) you can not do this with Autotools (or plain Makefiles for that matter).