# How to use module `std` with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-modules

The following test program

```
import std;
int main() {}
```

compiled with `gcc-14`

```
/usr/local/bin/g++  -g -std=c++23 -fconcepts -fmodules-ts -O3 -Wall -Wextra test400.cc --output test400
```

gives the following errors:

```
std: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
std: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/std.gcm'
std: note: imports must be built before being imported
std: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
```

The standard library module `std` should be available, but obviously is not.

Aside from header units: is the a way to create the `std` module by my own?

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1428832/792417

Comment: `import std` is a C++23 feature (and modules in general a C++20 feature). We are in early 2023, so ... `std module` may not be available yet. -- but you come from future, so we do not known. (gcc-14 is not yet released).

Comment: "_The standard library module std should be available, but obviously is not._": That's a very new C++23 feature. Do you know whether GCC even claims to already support it?

Comment: You could check the feature flags `__cpp_lib_modules` (C++23 `std` modules) and `__cpp_modules` (C++20 modules), to verify the features are available by your compiler.

Comment: Do you mean g++13? 13.1 just came out last week, so I'm going to guess that was a typo...

Comment: I use git master and self-compile the gcc. This actually gives version 14.

Comment: @wimalopaan: yeah, but if you use such version, you should be aware that it is not "version 14", but a development for "version 14" (so very different to the future version 14 which will be released. I'm in the opinion if you use "version 14", and someone in future will google it, it may get more confusion, so please (to all people): never call a version X if it was not released [it may be ok for few finals betas]; any development version should be clearly marked [and so we know that there are huge amount of bugs, and unimplemented things])

Answer (score 6):

GCC's libstdc++ does not support [P2465R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2465r3.pdf) yet, which allows for `import std;`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23

Note that C++23 is not yet finalized