# Cannot compile import std

Tags: c++, c++23, c++-modules

Can't make example from book work. I'm using VSCode and G++12. The code is

```
import std;

int main()
{
    int a{42};
    std::println(a);

    return 0;
}
```

and the CMakeLists is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(exercises
        VERSION 1.0
        LANGUAGES CXX)
                
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-12")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fmodules-ts -ggdb -Werror -Wall -Wpedantic)
```

But when I try to compile it I get errors

```
In module imported at /home/m/programming/c++/exercises/general_exercises/src/main.cpp:1:1:
std: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
std: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/std.gcm’
std: note: imports must be built before being imported
std: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

The book gives no information on how to compile given code, so any help will be appreciated.

I've tried to use Clang, but I have no experience with it, so just got some other errors...

Comment: "_from book_": Which book? The syntax is very new and compilers don't generally implement it yet. In particular libstdc++, the standard library implementation used by both GCC and sometimes Clang hasn't implemented this syntax yet at all (even in newer versions than GCC 12). The standard (C++23) that introduced this syntax hasn't even been published yet. The book is describing the future, not the generally-supported current language (which would be C++20 at most).

Comment: @user17732522: It may not be technically published, but it's been feature-complete with the final version informally published for nearly a year. Not saying you can expect immediate compiler support, but your comment makes it sound like it's still changing, when at this point it's mostly just typo fixes and defect reports like any other iteration of the standard.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I made it sound a bit exaggerated there. But I do wonder why there are apparently published books introducing the language that don't clearly mention the potential lack of compiler-support at publication time, especially if it seems to be geared towards people new to C++.

Comment: G++ does not support this. Clang partially supports it. Msvc is currently the only compiler which supports this. You can see compiler support for features here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: If you have access to a Windows system, you can download Visual Studio Community Edition for free. It supports `import std;`. Once you start using `import std;`, you will become addicted. No more stopping to scroll up, and type out another `#include` directive. Good riddance to all of that!

Comment: @user17732522: "*why there are apparently published books introducing the language that don't clearly mention the potential lack of compiler-support at publication time*" Because non-electronic books can't be changed. Such a warning will be increasingly out of date; next year, it might be irrelevant to everyone reading it. So the book choose not to date itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use module \`std\` with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154680/how-to-use-module-std-with-gcc)

Comment: @user17732522 the book is Beginning C++23 from beginner to pro 7th edition.

Comment: @ProMike According to [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Ivor-Horton/dp/1484293428) the back cover says "_All you need are Beginning C++23 and any recent C++ compiler [...]_", which I'd say is very misleading. There is at best only one compiler (MS Visual C++) for one platform (Windows) that can currently be used in conjunction with the book. Other common compilers like GCC and Clang, even most recently released versions, are not going to work with the language as the book seems to introduce it at the moment. It is likely going to work with other compilers in some months or a year, though.

Comment: @ProMike (That's of course trusting you that the book only gives example code in the way you are showing in your question and assuming that the introduction of the book doesn't clarify this problem and provide a workaround solution for the as of yet unimplemented features of the C++23. I don't have a copy of the book, so I can't say anything about that.)